# Right click mouse event

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mouselistener, swingutilities

I search through this forum but I can't find a good explanation on this topic.
Is there any different from the below statements? Which way is the better way to trigger this event?

```
if (evt.getButton() == 3)
```

Vs.

```
if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)**

this uses a bit operand to compare:

```
(evt.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK)
```

while other, just compare with a magic number that can change, I would rather change first comparison to:

```
if(evt.getButton() == java.awt.event.MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
```

---

**SwingUtilities** is part of the javax which comes with jdk, so I would prefer to delegate that responsabillity to this utility (helper) class, so in that case, **SwingUtilities** wins.

Comment: You should also add what might happen if the button for right mouse changes, but +1

Comment: for your second point . Because my mouseEvent is in the action
private void textareaMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) hence == 3